# Bind button header to variable + fix text in xaml

Tags: xaml, binding

I want to bind a button header to a file name, but I want to have fix text before and after the filename. Is this possible in xaml without code behind?

Something like that:

```
<Button Header="Save {Binding ActiveDocument.FileName} as..." Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.SaveAsCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have never tried that to be honest. But Binding object has StringFormat property.
So you can simply try this.

```
<Button Content="{Binding ActiveDocument.FileName, StringFormat='Save {0} as...'}" Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.SaveAsCommand}" />
```

another possible way is setting Buttons ContentStringFormat property

```
<Button Content="{Binding ActiveDocument.FileName}" ContentStringFormat="Save {0} as..." Command="{Binding ActiveDocument.SaveAsCommand}" />
```

Comment: I am really sorry, I tried and first solution doesn't work and I don't know why... because it should, but second one **works** just fine. And one more thing... there is third option but you have to write convertor and you don't want to touch the code.